# North African Dessert-Alexandria

Tags: dessert

I had a North African dessert when I was in Montreal called an Alexandria. I've searched high and low, but haven't been able to find an ingredient list, recipe, or any information on the dessert's origins. Does this dessert go by another name? [image]

It was very similar to a baklava, but had almonds instead of walnuts and wasn't as sweet. It didn't appear to have honey in it.

I found it at a farmer's market so there isn't a restaurant site or number to contact. I've attached a photo in case that is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to be from the "Le Ryad" Baklava place at the Marché Jean Talon.

You could get in touch with them via [instagram](https://www.instagram.com/leryadpatisseries/) or [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/Le-Ryad-P%C3%A2tisseries-356404097800643/); the product is in one of the photo on instagram.

It simply might be an inhouse product with a "Random" name that sound exotic.